# Pick specific result from REG QUERY search

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I'm trying to extract the **Windows 10 Logon background image** (from "Windows Spotlight") and copy it into another location for further use. So far I've successfully done it using the batch code provided below.

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=6 tokens=2*" %%A in ('REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Creative\ /F landscapeImage /S /V') DO (
  for %%F in (%%B) do (
    set Background=%%F
    goto :next
  )
)
:next
copy %Background% "d:\background.jpg" /Y
```

My biggest concern is that although it worked well on my machine, **the registry structure might look differently on other computers** and my code is totally unprepared for that.

The reason for this might be the blind guess with the `skip=6` parameter. The search in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Creative\` for `landscapeImage` returned 3 results and only the last one leads to the image that I'm seeing on the logon page. Since I didn't know how to pick specific search result, I used the `skip` parameter, but for this reason, the batch script will work properly only if there are at least 3 search results and the 3rd one is the one I'm actually looking for - in other instances it will simply fail.

To summarize, I don't know how to:

1. Check how many search results are returned from the `REG QUERY` command.
2. Pick a specific search result.

Another concern (unrelated to the batch script issue described above) is that I'm not sure how Windows decides which image is used as the background (it changes regularly). I just assumed that it's the last one from the search results (it was true in my case). I couldn't find any other mentions of the background image file within the registry. I tried looking for other parameters from that key, but that didn't return any results either. Any suggestions for this problem are also welcome.

This is the best I could come up with, but now I just simply got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider assigning all the query output to separate variables.  An array if you want to call it that.  This will assign all the images to an array of variables and give you a count of how many it found.

```
@echo off
set "cnt=0"
set "query=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Creative\"
for /F "TOKENS=1-2* delims= " %%G in (
    'REG QUERY %query% /F landscapeImage /S /V ^|find /I "landscapeImage"'
) DO (
    set /a "cnt+=1"
    CALL set "image%%cnt%%=%%I"
)
echo Number of Images=%cnt%
set image
pause
```

Note: On my computer, it also output 3 images and the last one is the current logon background image.

If you just want to set the last image to a variable just ditch the code that does the counting and use a basic set command.

```
set "image=%%I"
```

My logon background image changed again and the third image from the query is the logon screen image.  Seems to be consistent.

Comment: @pafflick only outputs three variables on my computer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be consistent. On my tablet there is only one entry (it is the image I'm seeing on the logon screen) while on my PC I'm seeing 9 entries now - it's the same 3 entries that I've seen previously, but each one is repeated two times for some reason. The subkeys have different numbers, but all of their contents are just duplicates - except for one entry which has different `contentId` value. None of this makes any sense to me, but so far, I've confirmed that it is true, that **the last entry contains the actual logon screen background**.

Comment: @pafflick then make the code change to just assign the last entry to a single variable.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I deleted my first comment as soon as I realized it was a problem on my side (I just spoke too soon). Could you please explain to me why the search query is "duplicated"? I don't understand why did you need to add this: `^|find /I "landscapeImage"` (I know the code doesn't work without it, I'm just trying to understand why). Also, how do I utilize the array id? I tried calling `image%cnt%` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here's the final batch code I use to extract the Windows 10 Logon background image (based on [Squashman](/users/1417694/squashman)'s answer):

```
@echo off
set "query=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Creative\"
for /F "TOKENS=1-2* delims= " %%G in (
    'REG QUERY %query% /F landscapeImage /S /V ^|find /I "landscapeImage"'
) DO (
    set "image=%%I"
)
copy %image% "d:\background.jpg" /Y
```

I put a shortcut to the batch file in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` to make a copy of the background image (from the so-called "Windows Spotlight") in the desired location on each system startup, so that the image stays "up-to-date".